# B43 Device Firmware Error - 12.04 Installation

Tags: 12.04, installation, firmware

Trying to install Ubuntu and I get this error.  Really have no idea what to do.  I tried to go the website it listed but I couldn't find anything close to what I have in this system.  I'm guessing I need a driver or something to complete the install?

Answer (score -1):

http://clusterbleep.net/blog/2012/05/09/ubuntu-12-04-splash-screen-lockup-with-livecd/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.